# Webbrowser control not working perfectly with proxies rotation

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, webbrowser-control

I am using many ipz and use them one after another some repeat after some time some with in seconds using this code:

```
  string key = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings";

  RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(key, true);

  RegKey.SetValue("ProxyServer", proxy);

  RegKey.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);

  webBrowser1.Navigate(customLinks[0].ToString());
```

The issue is its not always successful as i noticed many time.Suppose an ip is blocked so it takes the next one but i still see the block on the next one ,and even the next one.

So assuming its not taking proxy so fast etc?Maybe it needs to be refreshed.Kindly let me know how to implement this

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help from googling a lot , but do not remember the exact link:

Here is the code, i call the refresh function and pass proxy and it works 100 % everytime , anytime.

```
public struct Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
    {
        public int dwAccessType;
        public IntPtr proxy;
        public IntPtr proxyBypass;
    };

    [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
    private static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength);

    private void RefreshIESettings(string strProxy)
    {
        const int INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY = 38;
        const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY = 3;

        Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO struct_IPI;



        // Filling in structure
        struct_IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY;
        struct_IPI.proxy = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(strProxy);
        struct_IPI.proxyBypass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local");

        // Allocating memory
        IntPtr intptrStruct = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI));

        // Converting structure to IntPtr
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct_IPI, intptrStruct, true);

        bool iReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI));


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to set a single proxy in the browser, and implement that proxy yourself, such that it rotates requests to your proxy list.

Comment: I did not understand this can you please explain

Comment: Write an HTTP proxy. Point the browser only at that proxy. Program the proxy to make requests via the proxies in your list. Or you could repurpose an existing implementation, for instance: http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/

Comment: :|..is there no way that my implementation remains the same and works?Also can you please provide example for above.